# existence of Matrix as an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

let $U$ be a subspace in $F^n$, let $V$ be a subspace in $F^m$, 
prove the existence of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ such that
$\text{Row}(A) = U$ and $\text{Col}(A) = V$

ok, um I forgot to mention that $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$

can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

In general, such a matrix does not exist. If, say for example $U = \{0\}$ and $V = F^m \ne \{0\}$, then ${\rm Row}(A) = \{0\}$ gives $A = 0$, but ${\rm Col}(0) \ne V = F^m$.

---

Under the condition $\dim U = \dim V$ you added, the conclusion is true. Choose bases $B_U = (u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ of $U$ and $B_V = (v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ of $V$ and set 
$$ A = \sum_{i=1}^k v_i \cdot u_i^t $$

Comment: what if U and V are not {0} ?

Comment: sorry can you explain the summation part? is that dot product?
but u and v are in $F^n$ and $F^m$ respectively

Comment: That is matrix product. We multiply $v_i \in F^{n \times 1}$ with $u_i^t \in F^{1 \times m}$ to give a matrix $v_i u_i^t \in F^{n \times m}$. For example ($n=m=2$):
$$ \binom 12 \cdot (1 \;\; -1) =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 2 & -2 \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

The added condition that $\text{dim}(U) =\text{dim}(V)$  is necessary, because row rank = column rank.  Let ${\bf r}_1, \ldots, {\bf r}_d$ be a basis of $U$
(represented as row vectors) and ${\bf c}_1, \ldots, {\bf c}_d$ a basis of $V$ (represented as column vectors), and take $A = {\bf c}_1 {\bf r}_1 + \ldots + {\bf c}_d {\bf r}_d$.